# How to tell TikZ to first compute and then display a variable?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I want `TikZ` to first compute and then display the value of a variable. The question is, for sake of simplicity, based on [this concrete example from TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/cycle/):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \n {5}
\def \radius {3cm}
\def \margin {8} % margin in angles, depends on the radius

\foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
{
  \node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$\s$};
  \draw[->, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
    arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Suppose I messed up and I wanted my labels to run from 0 to n-1, instead of from 1 to n. How can I tell TikZ to first compute the difference or whatever operation on the variable, and then display it:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \n {5}
\def \radius {3cm}
\def \margin {12} % margin in angles, depends on the radius

\foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
{
  \node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$\s-1$};
  \draw[->, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
    arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I even used a temporary auxiliary variable \r=\s-1 but it still prints the following instead the nodes' numbers from 0 to n-1:  [image]

Remark: I know the problem would be solved by defining another range for `\s`, i.e. `{0,...,\n-1}` but I already wrote a *similar* code (but long, so it wouldn't be a MWE if I post it) based on this, with dependence on the `\s` and I wouldn't like to shift lot of times the variable to `\s+1` in the somehow long formulas.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To number objects from 0 up to value n-1, it is possible to use `evaluate` or `count` keys. Both are illustrated in the pgfmanual while explaining `foreach` operation. An example with the latter:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \n {5}
\def \radius {3cm}
\def \margin {12} % margin in angles, depends on the radius

\foreach \s[count=\xi from 0] in {1,...,\n}
{
  \node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$\xi$};
  \draw[->, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
    arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Complement to Claudio's answer without additional variables, for not so complicated arithmetic, you can use eTeX's `\numexpr` but to make it work in the math mode in terms of expansion, you need to add `\number` in front of it.

```
{$\number\numexpr\s-1\relax$};
```

For the remaining parts you can do the math computation via `pgfmath` engine.

```
 {\pgfmathparse{int(\s-1)}\pgfmathresult};
```

Both give the same result as Claudio's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\degrees[5]
\psset{radius=12pt,arcsep=36pt,arrows=->}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-4,-4)(4,4)
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,5}{\rput(4;\the\numexpr\i-1){\Circlenode{N\i}{\the\numexpr\i-1}}}
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,5}{\psarc(0,0){4}{(N\i)}{(N\the\numexpr\i+1)}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Notes

Consider `\foreach \i in {1,2,...,5}{\psarc(0,0){4}{(N\i)}{(N\the\numexpr\i+1)}}`. If `\i=5` then `\psarc(0,0){4}{(N5)}{(N6)}` but `N6` does not exist and no error is generated. PSTricks is so smart!